# Populate PayPal sandox account with lots of transactions

Tags: paypal, transactions

I am building a website and I want to import the users PayPal transaction history using the API.

My issue is that the PayPal sandbox accounts do not have any transaction history. I need to be able to test getting a 500+ transactions from the API.

Has anybody got any suggestions on a good way to create or import transaction data into the sandbox account? I have a CSV of the transactions from my account which has a few thousand records but I can't see a way to import it on the sandbox account.

Answer (score 0):

What you'll want to do is access the history of the transactions via the sandbox.paypal.com and not the transaction history via the developer portal.

1. You cannot import history data into PayPal because the data should be in the dashboard; counterintutive
2. You should be able to see the transactions in each merchant account via sandbox.paypal.com using the email and pw you created for each one

Hope this helps

Comment: Ok, any suggestions on a way to just create a few hundred test transactions?

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't a pre-built api for this, however that doesn't mean you can't build the logic to submit 100's of transaction in one submission as PayPal processes 1 transaction per 15secs. So to answer your question you can, however you'll create the logic to submit it on a per transaction basis in a logical batch. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Callum did you ever find an automated solution for this?